# Finding the mean ($\bar{y}$ vector) given $y$ vector

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $y$ be an $n \times 1$ vector of observations. Consider the $n \times 1$ vector $\bar{y}$, which contains the mean of $y$ vector. How does one show that the $\bar{y}$ vector is given by $$\bar{y}=\vec{1} \left( \vec{1}^T \vec{1} \right)^{-1} \vec{1}^Ty$$ where $\vec{1}$ is the vector of ones (also $n \times 1$).

Comment: What are your thoughts? How is $\overline y$ defined? Without this defintion your question is nonsense.

Comment: @amsmath I think its the mean of the y vector.

Comment: Please spell out the full context. Where is this related to linear regression?

Comment: @StubbornAtom Sorry, I don't think linear regression is directly related to the solution to this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by the mean of $y$ vector?

Comment: @StubbornAtom All entries in $\bar{y}$ are identical and given by the mean of $y$

Comment: @StubbornAtom Please do not change the formatting of my posts.

Comment: @Surb I heard you. No need to repeat the same thing.

Comment: @StubbornAtom ah, I was not you sure you got pinged by the first comment (which was under my post).

Comment: I changed $n\text{ x } 1$ to $n\times 1.$ That is standard usage. $\qquad$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\displaystyle\color{blue}{\vec{1}^Ty} = \sum_{i=1}^n 1\cdot y_i=\sum_{i=1}^n y_i$

$\displaystyle\color{red}{\vec{1}^T\vec{1}}=\sum_{i=1}^n 1\cdot 1 =n$

$\displaystyle\color{green}{({\vec{1}^T\vec{1}})^{-1}\,{\vec{1}^Ty}}=\frac{1}{\color{red}{\vec{1}^T\vec{1}}}\,\color{blue}{\vec{1}^Ty} =\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i=\bar y$

$\displaystyle\vec{1}\,\color{green}{({\vec{1}^T\vec{1}})^{-1}\,{\vec{1}^Ty}}=\vec{1}\bar y$

Comment: +1.  Perhaps worth noting that $\vec{1}^Ty$ and $\vec{1}^T\vec{1}$ and $(\vec{1}^T\vec{1})^{-1}$ and $(\vec{1}^T\vec{1})^{-1}\vec{1}^Ty$ are all $1 \times 1$ matrices

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's cleaner when written with inner products:

$$\overline{y} = \frac1n \begin{bmatrix} y_1+ \cdots + y_n \\ \vdots \\ y_1+ \cdots + y_n\end{bmatrix} = \left\langle y, \frac{\vec{1}}{\|\vec{1}\|}\right\rangle\frac{\vec{1}}{\|\vec{1}\|} = \frac1{\|\vec{1}\|^2}\langle y, \vec{1}\rangle 
\vec{1} = \frac1{\vec{1}^T\vec{1}}(\vec{1}^Ty)\vec{1} = \vec{1}(\vec{1}^T\vec{1})^{-1}(\vec{1}^Ty)$$